# Can I get a loan on my home by mortgage I am a pensioner and son is in states

Tags: india, home-loan, heloc, reverse-mortgages

I am looking at a loan of Rs 15 lakhs on my home. I own a property in Kalyan. I am a pensioner. My son will repay he is in United States

Answer (score 1):

You can get loan against property. Generally you need to establish cash flow to show that you will be able to pay this back. Being a pensioner the Bank needs to be convinced that you will be able to pay back.

Depending on your need, you can also look for Reverse-Mortgage. There are few Banks in India who would offer this; essentially they will pay you a monthly sum for a defined number of years. At the end they own the property.